# Abrir y cerrar el contenido de un widget de acordeón de Jet Engine clicando en el elemento grid que lo contiene

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

Muy buenas.

Tengo esta web tipo Listings con Elementor y Jet Engine que actualiza contenido de manera dinámica a través de Custom Post y Custom Fields.

He creado primero un listing como una "tarjeta" con contenido dinámico. Dentro de esta tarjeta, hay un elemento de Jet Engine tipo acordeón que despliega contenido también dinámico de otra plantilla.

Me gustaría poder plegar y desplegar este contenido pulsando en la tarjeta en sí y no tan solo en el elemento acordeón. Inspeccionando en el navegador, podréis ver el elemento tipo toggle que dice "Saber más" que quita y pone la clase "active-toggle" al clicar el toggle.

Sé que podría hacer esto con JavaScript pero tengo poca experiencia aún. ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Esta es la web en cuestión: [https://bolsadepuntos.com/](https://bolsadepuntos.com)

El HTML generado es el siguiente

```
<div data-elementor-type="jet-listing-items" data-elementor-id="569" class="elementor elementor-569">
    <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-50dbd533 elementor-hidden-tablet elementor-hidden-mobile elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="50dbd533" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">

            </div>
            <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-164ff6a8" data-id="164ff6a8" data-element_type="column">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-bb9eddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="bb9eddb" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Aulacem</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-344744d7 elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-accordion" data-id="344744d7" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-accordion.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <div class="jet-accordion" data-settings="{&quot;collapsible&quot;:false,&quot;ajaxTemplate&quot;:false,&quot;switchScrolling&quot;:false,&quot;switchScrollingOffset&quot;:0}" role="tablist">
                                <div class="jet-accordion__inner">
                                    <div class="jet-accordion__item jet-toggle jet-toggle-move-up-effect">
                                        <div id="jet-toggle-control-8771" class="jet-toggle__control elementor-menu-anchor" data-toggle="1" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="jet-toggle-content-8771" aria-expanded="false" data-template-id="838">
                                            <div class="jet-toggle__label-icon jet-toggle-icon-position-right"><span class="jet-toggle__icon icon-normal jet-tabs-icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span><span class="jet-toggle__icon icon-active jet-tabs-icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></div><div class="jet-toggle__label-text">Saber más</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="jet-toggle-content-8771" class="jet-toggle__content" data-toggle="1" role="tabpanel" data-template-id="838" style="height: 0px;">
                                            <div class="jet-toggle__content-inner">
                                                <!-- Contenido del acordion -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Agrega el codigo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Añade un ejemplo minimo completo y verificable, las preguntas que no demuestran una investigacion o trabajo previas suelen ser eliminadas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo primero es determinar cuál es el elemento que tiene enlazado el evento click, el cual origina que se abra o cierre el acordión. En tu caso son los que tienen la clase `jet-toggle__control`

Paso 1: Crear un código que se ejecute al inicio.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   //Todo lo de acá se ejecuta luego de que el DOM haya sido renderizado
});
```

Paso 2: Asignar el evento `click` a todo el recuadro es decir  a la clase `jet-listing-grid__item`. Para esto buscamos todos los elementos con aquella clase, los recorremos y asignamos el evento.

Luego buscamos el elemento `jet-toggle__control` que tiene la acción de abrir y cerrar y lo obligamos hacer `click`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  e.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.querySelector(".jet-toggle__control").click();
  });
});
```

Paso 3: Hasta acá el código funciona, pero existe el problema de que al hacer click en "Saber más" se abre y se cierra el acordión, esto sucede porque este botón tambien es parte del "todo". Entonces al presionarlo se ejecuta tanto el click global como el del mismo botón "Saber más".

Para solucionar esto, cancelaremos la propagación de eventos del botón "Saber más"

Código final :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  e.querySelector(".jet-toggle__control").addEventListener("click", function(){
   event.stopPropagation();
 });
 
  e.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.querySelector(".jet-toggle__control").click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hola, muy buenas.

Muchísimas gracias por el aporte! Finalmente utilicé JQuery para resolverlo. Adjunto código:
```jQuery(".jet-listing-grid__items").on("click", ".jet-listing-grid__item", function(){
  jQuery(this).find(".jet-toggle__content").toggleClass("active");
  jQuery(this).find(".jet-accordion__item").removeClass("active-toggle");
 });```